# C# WPF OneWayToSource binding not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have the following code in my xaml file:

```
<WrapPanel Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
            <Label Content="Azonosító:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtId" Width="80" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent.Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="Név:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Width="100" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent.Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="Cím:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtAddress" Width="150" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent.Address, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Label Content="Kar:"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="txtFaculty" Width="50" Text="{Binding Path=SelectedStudent.Faculty, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </WrapPanel>

...

<DataGrid x:Name="dgdStudents" Grid.Row="1" Background="White" BorderBrush="LightGray" CanUserAddRows="False" 
              CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" Cursor="Hand"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Students}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" 
              SelectionUnit="FullRow" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStudent, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
```

As you can see, I'm binding SelectedStudent in the WrapPanel with TwoWay mode and with OneWayToSource mode in the DataGrid. However, whenever I select a row in the datagrid and modify the values in the textbox, the selected row also changes according to the modifications. Why?

Comment: `SelectedStudent` is something altogether different then property of selected student. `TextBox` affect properties of student class which are reflected as columns in `DataGrid` by default bound two way

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. Can you be a little bit more specific?

Comment: Each column has its own binding to a property of an item behind an item and it has nothing to do with `SelectedItem`. What you have is binding which ensures that if `SelectedPerson` property change to another person selected row will not be affected. But if any property of any item changes it will still be reflected

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Any possible workarounds?

Comment: @PéterBencze use a default binding mode, make a copy of the SelectedStudent like SelectedStudentToEdit, change its values, update the original SelectedStudent with values of SelectedStudentToEdit if needed.